# How do I make the header into two lines and the logo to the right of the first line?

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox

I've been trying to create a site header with the site name on 2 lines and its logo on the first line. I've tried both CSS Grid and Flex, but in this case I have to do it only through absolute, which will make the site not adaptive and not scalable.

```css
.header.main {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.site-title {
  display: flex;
}

.big-logo {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 300px;
  width: 141px;
  height: 136px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.graficlogo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

h1.main-title {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Neue Machina';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 128px;
  line-height: 95.36px;
  color: #EDFB3A;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="header main">

  <div class="site-title">
    <div class="big-logo">
      <img class="graficlogo" src="assets/img/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
    </div>
    <h1 class="main-title">
      мои <br> достижения
    </h1>
  </div>
  <p>
    онлайн-платформа централизации достижений и развития активной деятельности
  </p>

</div>
```

Вот то, что получилось:
[логотип находится слева и сдвигает надпись](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CQ88.png)

Вот то, что ожидалось:
[логотип находится справа от первой строки заголовка и не мешает отображению надписи](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na422.png)

Comment: Please note that this is an English language-only website, so the text of the question must be in English (including the links, and the text before the links). It also helps if the code/demo is in English so we can interpret any clarification you may make. Given that the first part of your question is written in English I imagine you must understand/use the language well enough? If not, however, there's also [ru.so] if you'd prefer.

Comment: if you cannot modify your structure, nor by hand, nor via javascript, then you need to be tricky. an average trick could be something playing with width, flex,max-width and scale: https://jsfiddle.net/d1j7x6as/ Best is to use the proper structure not trying to bend yours via CSS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :

```css
.header.main {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.site-title {
}

.graficlogo {
  width: 141px;
  height: 136px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

h1.main-title {
  font-family: 'Neue Machina';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 128px;
  line-height: 95.36px;
  color: #EDFB3A;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="header main">

  <div class="site-title">
    <h1 class="main-title">
      мои <img class="graficlogo" src="assets/img/Logo.png" alt="Logo"><br> достижения
    </h1>
  </div>
  <p>
    онлайн-платформа централизации достижений и развития активной деятельности
  </p>

</div>
```